# Show that $\int_0^\pi f(\sin\theta) \, d\theta = 2\int_0^{\pi/2}f(\sin\theta) \, d\theta$

Tags: integration

The full question states:

> Show that $$\int_0^\pi f(\sin\theta)\,d\theta = 2\int_0^{\pi/2}f(\sin\theta)\,d\theta$$ for an arbitrary function $f$ defined in the interval $[-1, 1].$

Having tried out different possible functions for $f$ (rational, radical, exponential, etc.) I know that the equation indeed holds true, but I have no clue as to how to go about proving it. It has been suggested to me that the proof might involve the use of multivalued functions since a particular interval was defined but I don't see how this could be the case since neither the sine nor complex sine functions are multivalued as far as I know.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Compare `sin\theta`: $sin\theta$, with `\sin\theta`: $\sin\theta$.  Back slash before trig functions.  But thanks for taking the time to format; your post was clear; I just prettied it up a smidgen.

Comment: Can you split the left-side integral into intervals $[0,\pi/2] $ and $[\pi/2,\pi]$, then use new variable $v=\pi-\theta $ in the second interval integral to show that it is equal to the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe “arbitrary” is too much, because the integral may not exist. Let's assume $f$ is Riemann integrable, instead (or, less generally, continuous).

Rewrite the integral as
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(\sin\theta)\,d\theta+
\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}f(\sin\theta)d\theta
$$
and try the substitution $\theta=\pi-\varphi$ in the second summand.